# Filter out speaker output from microphone input - Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, video, microphone, speakers

I just recieved my new Macbook Pro (2013 version) and I have one problem. I know most computers don't do this, but does anybody know of anyway I could stop my microphone (built into the Mac) from picking up the output from the (built in) speakers? In my Windows laptop, I installed some Realtek drivers that would do this for me, and it was nearly perfect. I could play a video/audio, and talk to somebody on Skype/whatever, without having the person I am talking to hear the video.

Are there any drivers out there for Mac that do this, as it is a bit frustrating to listen to music/watch videos, and know that the other person can hear it.

Thanks.